# Tomar una fila de Mysql con PHP sin while

Tags: php, mysql

Hola si me pudieran ayudar,estoy tratando de tomar una fila de una tabla de Mysql,no necesito recorrer la tabla solo quiero tomar una sola fila.

```
$consulta_precio_seco="SELECT * FROM secos WHERE codigo=10" ;
$resultados_precio_seco=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta_precio_seco);
$fila=mysqli_fetch_row($resultados_cargar);
echo $fila[0];
```

Alguien me ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te consulta debería quedar del modo siguiente asumiendo que solo quieres obtener los valores de cada columna pero de una sola fila

```
<?php

$consulta_precio_seco="SELECT * FROM mensajes" ;
$resultados_precio_seco=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta_precio_seco);
$fila=mysqli_fetch_row($resultados_precio_seco);
//así si quieres que los resultados salgan concatenados
echo $fila[0].' '.$fila[1].' '.$fila[2];
```

Si deseas que los resultados se vean uno por renglón

```
  $consulta_precio_seco="SELECT * FROM mensajes" ;
    $resultados_precio_seco=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta_precio_seco);
    $fila=mysqli_fetch_row($resultados_precio_seco);
    echo $fila[0].PHP_EOL;
    echo $fila[1].PHP_EOL;
    echo $fila[2].PHP_EOL;
```

Como puedes notar los cambios hechos son mínimos, pero son los siguientes

> 1. a la función `mysqli_fetch_row()` le paso por dentro la variable `$resultados_precio_seco`, pues es la que contiene el conjunto de resultados que vienen directo de tu query
> 2. La data que te esta siendo regresada viene dentro de un array por lo cual cuando haces el echo debes indicar la posición de las clumnas
>      que deseas leer, por ejemplo en la tabla id, name, email id esta en la
>      posición 0, name en la posición 1 y email en la posición 2 (solo como
>      ejemplo)

Answer (score 3):

`mysqli_fetch_row` debe recibir como parámetro un conjunto de resultados, que se obtiene con `mysqli_query`.

En tu código ese conjunto de resultados se llama `$resultados_precio_seco`, pero tú estás pasando otra variable que es `$resultados_cargar`.

Para resolver el problema sería entonces:

```
$fila=mysqli_fetch_row($resultados_precio_seco);
echo $fila[0];
```

> **NOTA SOBRE OPTIMIZACIÓN:**
>
> Si solamente te interesa una fila, quizá conviene que limites los
>   resultados a una fila, para no sobrecargar a la base de datos y al
>   servidor trayendo datos innecesarios. Puedes por tanto escribir la
>   consulta así: `SELECT * FROM secos WHERE codigo=10 LIMIT 1`

---

> **NOTA SOBRE *CONVENCIÓN DE NOMBRES***
>
> Convendría quizá que uses nombres de variable menos extensos. Si bien esto no es ninguna dificultad para el funcionamiento del código, sí lo es a la hora de leerlo, escribirlo, analizarlos, organizarlo, comprenderlo.  No es lo mismo tener una variable llamada `$resultados_precio_seco` que si la llamas por ejemplo `$rsPrecioSeco` o tener `$consulta_precio_seco` en vez de `$sqlPrecioSeco`.